# Angularjs - NgTable got undefined in reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, ngtable

i'm using Angularjs NgTable, with pagination inside of a `tab` provided by Angularjs Material. this works fine. i've used it in many parts of my project and realoaded it many times in differents parts.

but in this case, i can't reload the tables. and don't know what is the problem or how shoud do the reload.

i have in `DistribucionController` this functions:

```
$scope.listaFacturaTierra = function () {
    var idFactura = $stateParams.idFactura;
    $facturaTierra = distribucionService.getStockTierra(idFactura);
    $facturaTierra.then(function (datos) {
        $scope.facturaTierra = datos.data;
        var data = datos;
        $scope.tableFacturaTierra = new NgTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 8
        }, {
            total: data.length,
            getData: function (params) {
                data = $scope.facturaTierra;
                params.total(data.length);
                if (params.total() <= ((params.page() - 1) * params.count())) {
                    params.page(1);
                }
                return data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            }});
    });
};

$scope.listaFacturaBebelandia = function () {
    var idFactura = $stateParams.idFactura;
    $facturaBebelandia = distribucionService.getStockBebelandia(idFactura);
    $facturaBebelandia.then(function (datos) {
        var data = datos.data;
        $scope.facturaBebelandia = datos.data;
        $scope.tableFacturaBebelandia = new NgTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 10
        }, {
            total: data.length,
            getData: function (params) {
                data = $scope.facturaBebelandia;
                params.total(data.length);
                if (params.total() <= ((params.page() - 1) * params.count())) {
                    params.page(1);
                }
                return data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            }});
    });
};
$scope.listaFacturaLibertador = function () {
    var idFactura = $stateParams.idFactura;
    $facturaLibertador = distribucionService.getStockLibertador(idFactura);
    $facturaLibertador.then(function (datos) {
        var data = datos.data;
        $scope.facturaLibertador = datos.data;
        $scope.tableFacturaLibertador = new NgTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 10
        }, {
            total: data.length,
            getData: function (params) {
                data = $scope.facturaLibertador;
                params.total(data.length);
                if (params.total() <= ((params.page() - 1) * params.count())) {
                    params.page(1);
                }
                return data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            }});
    });
};
```

they are displayed fine, and the pagination is working as well.

i add elements using Angularjs Material ngDialog using 3 functions the make the process.

Show the principal modal:

```
$scope.distribuirModal = function (producto) {
    $rootScope.modalProducto = producto;
    ngDialog.open({
        template: 'views/modals/distribucion/modal-distribuir.html',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-advertencia',
        showClose: false,
        controller: 'DistribucionController',
        closeByDocument: false,
        closeByEscape: false
    });
};
```

make the processs of the data, and show a modal of confirmation:

```
$scope.confirmarDistribuir = function (modalDistribuir) {
    var control = 0;
    control = modalDistribuir.tierra + modalDistribuir.bebelandia + modalDistribuir.libertador;
    if (control === $rootScope.modalProducto.cantidadTotal) {
        if (modalDistribuir.tierra !== null) {
            $scope.wrapper.stockTierra.idProducto = $rootScope.modalProducto;
            $scope.wrapper.stockTierra.cantidad = modalDistribuir.tierra;
        }
        if (modalDistribuir.bebelandia !== null) {
            $scope.wrapper.stockBebelandia.idProducto = $rootScope.modalProducto;
            $scope.wrapper.stockBebelandia.cantidad = modalDistribuir.bebelandia;
        }
        if (modalDistribuir.libertador !== null) {
            $scope.wrapper.stockLibertador.idProducto = $rootScope.modalProducto;
            $scope.wrapper.stockLibertador.cantidad = modalDistribuir.libertador;
        }
        ngDialog.open({
            template: 'views/modals/distribucion/confirmacion-distribuir.html',
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-advertencia',
            showClose: false,
            controller: 'DistribucionController',
            closeByDocument: false,
            closeByEscape: false,
            data: {
                'wrapper': $scope.wrapper,
                'producto': $rootScope.modalProducto
            }
        });
    } else {
        $scope.alerts.push({
            type: 'danger',
            msg: 'La cantidad total de productos a distribuir debe ser igual a la cantidad total de productos en almacen.'
        });
    }
};
```

in this modal i execute a function that save the data on my API

```
$scope.finalizarDistribucion = function () {
    $scope.sendWrapper = {
        stockTierra: null,
        stockBebelandia: null,
        stockLibertador: null
    };
    if ($scope.ngDialogData.wrapper.stockTierra.idProducto !== null && $scope.ngDialogData.wrapper.stockTierra.cantidad) {
        $scope.sendWrapper.stockTierra = $scope.ngDialogData.wrapper.stockTierra;
    }
    if ($scope.ngDialogData.wrapper.stockBebelandia.idProducto !== null && $scope.ngDialogData.wrapper.stockBebelandia.cantidad) {
        $scope.sendWrapper.stockBebelandia = $scope.ngDialogData.wrapper.stockBebelandia;
    }
    if ($scope.ngDialogData.wrapper.stockLibertador.idProducto !== null && $scope.ngDialogData.wrapper.stockLibertador.cantidad) {
        $scope.sendWrapper.stockLibertador = $scope.ngDialogData.wrapper.stockLibertador;
    }
    $distribute = distribucionService.add($scope.sendWrapper);
    $distribute.then(function (datos) {
        if (datos.status === 200) {
            ngDialog.closeAll();
            toaster.pop({
                type: 'success',
                title: 'Exito',
                body: 'Se ha distribuido con exito los productos.',
                showCloseButton: false
            });
        }
    });
    $scope.$emit('updateTables', $scope.ngDialogData.producto);
    $scope.$emit('updateStock', {});
};
```

in this function i do two `$emit`

the first one update my object `Producto` in my `ProductoController` and send a `$broadcast` to update my principal table

```
$scope.$on('updateTables', function (event, object) {
    var idFactura = parseInt($stateParams.idFactura);
    object.estadoDistribucion = true;
    $updateProducto = _productoService.update(object);
    $updateProducto.then(function (datos) {
        if (datos.status === 200) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('updateTableProducto', {'idFactura': idFactura});
        }
    });
});
```

this last works fine, reload the table without problems.

the second `$emit` is the problem, it must reload the another 3 tables

```
$scope.$on('updateStock', function () {
    var idFactura = parseInt($stateParams.idFactura);
    $facturaTierra = distribucionService.getStockTierra(idFactura);
    $facturaTierra.then(function (datos) {
        $scope.facturaTierra = datos.data;
        $scope.tableFacturaTierra.reload();
    });
    $facturaBebelandia = distribucionService.getStockBebelandia(idFactura);
    $facturaBebelandia.then(function (datos) {
        $scope.facturaBebelandia = datos.data;
        $scope.tableFacturaBebelandia.reload();
    });
    $facturaLibertador = distribucionService.getStockLibertador(idFactura);
    $facturaLibertador.then(function (datos) {
        $scope.facturaLibertador = datos.data;
        $scope.tableFacturaLibertador.reload();
    });
});
```

but my parameters of ngTable are `undefined` and the reload fails.

have somebody any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after try many times i got the answer.

First in my `ProductoController` i did a `$broadcast` to my `DistribucionController`

```
$rootScope.$on('updateTableProducto', function (event, object) {
    $list = _productoService.searchByIdFactura(object.idFactura);
    $list.then(function (datos) {
        $scope.productosFactura = datos.data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('updateStock', {});
        $scope.tableProductosFactura.reload();
    });
});
```

then on i receive this `$broadcast` on my another controller using

```
$scope.$on('updateStock', function (event, object) {
    var idFactura = parseInt($stateParams.idFactura);
    $facturaTierra = distribucionService.getStockTierra(idFactura);
    $facturaTierra.then(function (datos) {
        $scope.facturaTierra = datos.data;
        $scope.tableFacturaTierra.reload();
    });
    $facturaBebelandia = distribucionService.getStockBebelandia(idFactura);
    $facturaBebelandia.then(function (datos) {
        $scope.facturaBebelandia = datos.data;
        $scope.tableFacturaBebelandia.reload();
    });
    $facturaLibertador = distribucionService.getStockLibertador(idFactura);
    $facturaLibertador.then(function (datos) {
        $scope.facturaLibertador = datos.data;
        $scope.tableFacturaLibertador.reload();
    });
});
```

NOTE: if i write `$rootScope.on` it execute 3 times. so in `$scope` just make one loop.

I hope this will be helpul to someone.